# problem to make dynamic a slider on laravel framework

Tags: php, laravel

I want to make a slider dynamic in the Php Laravel framework. there is 4 image that is sliding, title and description are fixed on each sliding...

View:-

```
   <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
    @foreach($sliders as $slider)
    <div class="aaa">
        <img src="{{ asset('/uploads/')}}/{{$slider->background_image }}" data-thumb="{{ asset('/uploads/')}}/{{$slider->background_image }}" alt="" height="615px" width="1263px">
        <div class="pra">
            <h1>{{$slider->title}}</h1>
            <p>{{$slider->description}}
               </p>
            <div class="btn-1">
                <a href="{{route('contactUs')}}">Contact US</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
```

`

Controller:-

```
public function index(){
        $sliders=home1::all();
 return view('User.userdashboard',compact('sliders'));

}`
```

Route:-

```
Route::get('/',['as'=>'construction','uses'=>'User\UserController@index']);
```

Actual Design of slider:-

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
<div class="aaa">
    <img src="images/banner-1.jpg" data-thumb="images/toystory.jpg" alt="" />

</div>

    <div class="aaa">
    <img src="images/banner-2.jpg" data-thumb="images/up.jpg" alt=""/>
        <div class="pra">
            <h1>    The Best Business Support</h1>
            <p>
                Preparing your money is a daunting challenge for today's investors.</p>

            <div class="btn-1">
                <a href="contact-us.html">Contact US</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="aaa">
    <img src="images/banner-3.jpg" data-thumb="images/walle.jpg" alt="" data-transition="slideInLeft" />
</div>

    <div class="aaa">
    <img src="images/banner-4.jpg" data-thumb="images/nemo.jpg" alt="" />
 </div>

</div>
```

`

I don't understand where to start the foreach loop so that only images are slide
when I add another data from admin panel with column 'image','title', 'description'
the images are  showing perfectly but title and description are overwrite

please help me in sorting out this problem

Answer (score 0):

actually in your controller you get a collection under `$sliders` variable.  `$sliders=home1::all();`.

You said that your `home1` Model have some columns like `'image', 'title', 'description'`.
So in your blade file you are getting `$sliders` because the `compact('slides')` instruction.

In that way your should be able to loop through `$sliders`just like as you are referencing in your question:

```
@foreach ($sliders as $slider)
<div class="aaa">
    <img src="{{ asset('/uploads/')}}/{{$slider->background_image }}" 
    data-thumb="{{ asset('/uploads/')}}/{{$slider->background_image }}" 
    alt="" height="615px" width="1263px">
    <div class="pra">
        <h1>{{$slider->title}}</h1>
        <p>{{$slider->description}}</p>
        <div class="btn-1">
            <a href="{{route('contactUs')}}">Contact US</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Here `$slider` contains each object from `$sliders` collection so you should see its own `title` and `description` alongside the `image` field.

You could test what `$sliders`contains by dumping the collection in your blade file, using `{{ dd($sliders) }}`.

Regards.

Comment: for first data:-original: array:6 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "background_image" => "1582304142.jpg"
        "title" => "INDIA"
        "description" => "I LOVE MY COUNTRY"
        "created_at" => "2020-02-21 16:55:42"
        "updated_at" => "2020-02-21 16:55:42"

Comment: second data:-#original: array:6 [▼
        "id" => 2
        "background_image" => "1582465941.jpg"
        "title" => "VOICE ASSISTANT"
        "description" => "dadi"
        "created_at" => "2020-02-23 13:52:21"
        "updated_at" => "2020-02-23 13:52:21"
      ]

Comment: all data are coming

Comment: Ok, as data is coming in $sliders variable, is the loop showing it accurately? Have you any other issue with it?